# I have this error: IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 19! Did I make a mistake?

Tags: python

```py
# Variables to represent the base hours and

# the overtime multiplier.

base_hours = 40

# Base hours per week

ot_multiplier = 1.5 # Overtime multiplier

# Get the hours worked and the hourly pay rate.

hours = float(input('Enter the number of hours worked: '))

pay_rate = float(input('Enter the hourly pay rate: '))

# Calculate and display the gross pay.

if hours > base_hours:

# Calculate the gross pay with overtime.

# First, get the number of overtime hours worked.

overtime_hours = hours - base_hours

# Calculate the amount of overtime pay.

overtime_pay = overtime_hours * pay_rate * ot_multiplier

# Calculate the gross pay.

gross_pay = base_hours * pay_rate + overtime_pay

else:

# Calculate the gross pay without overtime.

gross_pay = hours * pay_rate

# Display the gross pay.

print(f'The gross pay is ${gross_pay:,.2f}.')
```

Comment: Yes, I don't see any indentation after: `if hours > base_hours:`.

Comment: @Braham are you using an IDE for this? if not, I would suggest Pycharm as it's free and I use it all the time for python related stuff.

Comment: I use Pycharm as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements), everything inside of `if` and `else` statements statement must be indented. According to [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation), the indent should be 4 spaces.

so, your code should look like this:

```
if hours > base_hours:

    # Calculate the gross pay with overtime.

    # First, get the number of overtime hours worked.

    overtime_hours = hours - base_hours

    # Calculate the amount of overtime pay.

    overtime_pay = overtime_hours * pay_rate * ot_multiplier

    # Calculate the gross pay.

    gross_pay = base_hours * pay_rate + overtime_pay

else:

    # Calculate the gross pay without overtime.

    gross_pay = hours * pay_rate

# Display the gross pay.

print(f'The gross pay is ${gross_pay:,.2f}.')
```